# Permutations of a set of strings?

Tags: java, permutation

I have an array of strings, for example:

```
{ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" }
```

That I want to get all combinations of.

I tried using a method that I've used with charsets to generate all permutations:

```
public static void generate(String[] stringset, String pfx, int n, int k) {
    if (k == 0) {
        System.out.println(pfx);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        generate(stringset, pfx + stringset[i] + ",", n, k - 1);
    }
}
```

However I was unable to get a working output.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by all permutations? How does your answer need to be formatted? You can use a recursive function that combines the strings, in nested loops.

Comment: Search "powerset"...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea, using an ArrayList.

```
public static void generate(ArrayList<String> stringset, String pfx) {
    if (stringset.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println(pfx);
        return;
    }
    int len = stringset.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
        String first = stringset.remove(i);
        generate(stringset, pfx + first + ",");
        stringset.add(i,first);
    }
}
```